# Error modularizing a project with gluon Charm: The package com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins is accessible from more than one module

Tags: java, eclipse, java-module, gluon-mobile, java-platform-module-system

I'm going through modularizing my own projects. One of my classes uses the following imports:

```
import com.gluonhq.charm.down.Services;
import com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins.StorageService; // error here on "com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins"
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.AppBar;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.Dialog;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.SettingsPane;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.settings.DefaultOption;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.settings.Option;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.View;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.visual.MaterialDesignIcon;
```

In my `module-info.java` I have declared:

```
requires charm.glisten;
requires charm.down.core;
requires charm.down.plugin.storage;
```

as per auto-fix suggestions of Eclipse. However, I get the error specified for the above line:

```
The package com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins is accessible from more than one module:
charm.down.plugin.device,
charm.down.plugin.display,
charm.down.plugin.in.app.billing,
charm.down.plugin.lifecycle,
charm.down.plugin.push.notifications,
charm.down.plugin.runtime.args,
charm.down.plugin.statusbar,
charm.down.plugin.storage
```

The `charm` modules are automatically named since they are not Java modules apparently. This could be related to the issue. Before modularizing my projects, there were no such issues. How do I solve this?

`build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.gluonhq:client-gradle-plugin:0.1.30'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.9'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.21.2'
    id 'com.google.osdetector' version '1.6.2'
    id 'eclipse'
    id 'org.kordamp.gradle.jdeps' version '0.11.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.gluonhq.client-gradle-plugin'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

sourceCompatibility = 14
targetCompatibility = 14

ext.platform = osdetector.os == 'osx' ? 'mac' : osdetector.os == 'windows' ? 'win' : osdetector.os

dependencies {
    compile "org.openjfx:javafx-base:14:$platform"
    compile "org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:14:$platform"
    compile "org.openjfx:javafx-controls:14:$platform"
    compile "org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:14:$platform"

    runtimeOnly "org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:14:win"
    runtimeOnly "org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:14:mac"
    runtimeOnly "org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:14:linux"

    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.0-jdk9'
    compile 'org.reactfx:reactfx:2.0-M5'

    compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12"
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
}


javafx {
    version = "14"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
}

mainClassName = 'com.my.app.MainClass'
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.my.app.Launcher'
    }
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}

eclipse {
    classpath {
        downloadJavadoc = true
        downloadSources = true
    }
}

wrapper {
    gradleVersion = '6.5.1'
}
```

JDK 14
Eclipse 4.16
`buid.gradle` declares the dependency `'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.0-jdk9'` (I saw that version 6 exists, should I upgrade?)

Comment: Which JDK version are you using?

Comment: @JoséPereda 14, forgot to mention.

Comment: To run Java/JavaFX 11+, you need to move from the jfxmobile plugin (that was only working for Java 8 and 9) to the new Client plugin, see https://github.com/gluonhq/client-samples and https://docs.gluonhq.com/client/.

Comment: @JoséPereda I'm already using it. I added the build file to the question.

Comment: You need to migrate Charm Down to [Attach](https://github.com/gluonhq/attach) (should be straightforward), See https://github.com/gluonhq/client-samples/tree/master/Maven/HelloGluon

Comment: @JoséPereda That does the trick! Do I keep the full 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.0-jdk9' dependency that includes a few down services and just ignore them? Also, should I update to 6.0.5 (that I found [here](https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/gluonhq/charm/)) or is that not suitable for jdk9+?

Comment: Charm (Gluon Mobile) has been migrated to 6.0+, so that works with Java/JavaFX 11+. No need to keep old 5.0+ versions. Use the dependencies that HelloGluon uses.

Comment: @JoséPereda Works, thanks. You should post it as an answer. I wouldn't be surprised if others hit this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old Gluon `jfxmobile` plugin, that was used to create mobile applications with Java 1.8 or Java 9, is EOL.

To be able to run those mobile applications with Java/JavaFX 11+, you have to replace that plugin new Gluon Client plugin.

More details:

- [Client Maven plugin](https://github.com/gluonhq/client-maven-plugin),
- [Client basic samples](https://github.com/gluonhq/client-samples).
- [Documentation](https://docs.gluonhq.com/client).

One main difference, the new plugin uses Maven instead of Gradle. However, thanks to the community, there is also a version of the [Client plugin for Gradle](https://github.com/gluonhq/client-gradle-plugin), that might be a little bit behind the maven counterpart).

In order to migrate your project to Java 11+ and replace one plugin with the other, you have to modify your build file.

```
plugins {
    // new client plugin
    id 'com.gluonhq.client-gradle-plugin' version '0.1.30'

    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.9'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.21.2'
    id 'com.google.osdetector' version '1.6.2'
    id 'eclipse'
    id 'org.kordamp.gradle.jdeps' version '0.11.0'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

sourceCompatibility = 14
targetCompatibility = 14

dependencies {
   
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:6.0.5'
    compile 'org.reactfx:reactfx:2.0-M5'

    compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12"
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
}


javafx {
    version = "14"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
}

gluonClient {
 //    target = "ios"  // uncomment to deploy on iOS
 //    target = "android"  // uncomment to deploy on Android

      attachConfig {
         version = "4.0.8"
         services 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
     }
 }
```

You will notice the main changes:

- Charm (Gluon Mobile) is now 6.0+
- Charm Down has been renamed to [Attach](https://github.com/gluonhq/attach), current version is 4.0.8 (you will have to refactor the package names, like `com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins.StorageService` to `com.gluonhq.attach.storage.StorageService`).

You can still run the project with your JDK, with `./gradlew run` (using the JavaFX plugin).

With the new Client plugin you will also be able to create a native image, that will run on desktop (Windows, Linux, MacOS) and mobile (Android, iOS), leveraging GraalVM.

Following the [Client requirements](https://github.com/gluonhq/client-samples#requirements), download GraalVM for your host machine from [here](https://github.com/graalvm/graalvm-ce-dev-builds/releases), set `GRAALVM_HOME`, and you will be able to run:

```
// build the native image, it takes some time:
./gradlew clean nativeBuild
// run the native image
./gradlew nativeRun
```

And if you have a mobile device at hand, only by enabling the `target` to iOS or Android in your build will build and deploy the native image to that mobile platform.

Comment: For completness one should add that you can only build for Android from Linux and for iOS from macOS. Just to avoid disappointment in case you are on the wrong OS.